# what is difference between criterion and scoring in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, grid-search

I have created a GradientBoostingRegressor model.

I use **scoring** parameter in GridSearchCV function to return MSE score.

I wonder if I use **criterion** in **param_grids** does it change my model? which is the true way?

Thanks

```
    GBR = GradientBoostingRegressor()
    param_grids = {
                    'learning_rate'    : [0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 ],
                    'n_estimators'     : [50,60,70,80,90,100],
                    'max_depth'        : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'min_samples_leaf' : [1,2,3,5,10,15],
                    'min_samples_split': [2,3,4,5,10],  
                    #'criterion' : ['mse']
    }
        
    kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
    gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=GBR, param_grid = param_grids , cv = kf, n_jobs=-1, 
return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *criterion* method evaluates the split in the tree. The *scoring* method evaluates the quality of the model as a whole.

If you want to find out **if** it changes your model, why not just test it out? That's what GridSearchCV is good at. Default is *friedman_mse*, so:

```
param_grids = {
                    'learning_rate'    : [0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5 ],
                    'n_estimators'     : [50,60,70,80,90,100],
                    'max_depth'        : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'min_samples_leaf' : [1,2,3,5,10,15],
                    'min_samples_split': [2,3,4,5,10],  
                    'criterion' : ['friedman_mse', 'mse']
    }
```